# Combining all materials into one/few. over 200 Materials and textures. Complex meshes

Tags: texturing, materials, uv, uv-image-editor

I'm porting a model (A city) right now to Source Engine, which can only handle 32 Materials if compiled to .mdl.

The problem:

The Model has about 230 objects, now joined toegther with CTRL+J. Each object had its own Material and its own texture.

That means this combined "thing" has now 230 Materials and Textures.

Unwrapping this monster results in completely distorted textures everywhere, and the UV Image looks like a Black MIDI or something. Also if i'm in the Image Editor, there is a image already set (from the chosen material), and if i press X, the whole object/mesh turns white.

It can't be baked without proper UV Unwrapping as far as i know.. soo..

How can i combine all the materials & textures (230) into one? Any help is realy appreciated!

Best regards, 
Eric